# Is there any way to mock a request for websocket

Tags: c#, websocket, mocking

I have an application which receives data from different services. 
I am writing a test method to verify the application removing all the external dependencies.
I am using Fiddler to intercept the request being sent from the client to server and send my customized json response. It is working as expected with http(s) requests but not with WEBSOCKETS.

Is there any other tool that I can use in C# to mock the requests/responses for Websocket connections?

Answer (score 0):

A typical way is to wrap the call in a mockable interface call.

```
interface IWebSocketCaller
{
   Result GetData(); 
}
```

Implement this on both your actual class and mock class. 
You can also get this mock class using mocking framework like Moq

```
class MockWebCaller: IWebSocketCaller
{
    Result GetData()
    {
       // dummy result
        return new Results();
    }
}
```

Now supposing your calling class is something like this.

```
Class CleintClass{
IWebSocketCaller  _caller; 
 ClientClass(IWebSocketCaller caller)
 { 
    this._caller = caller; 
 }
 Result GetData()
 {
    return  this._caller.GetData();
  }
}
```

Now in test method use the instance of Client class which has mocked caller class.
Hope this helps.